# Web scraping for newbie

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm new to Python and web scraping. I was trying to extract data from Rentals.ca. My code is below and I couldn't retrieve any data from the website. I have tried other websites and successfully get the data. I have tried to follow some Youtube tutorials, but they didn't solve my problems.

````
from csv import writer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://rentals.ca/new-westminster?bbox=-123.20298,49.13647,-122.75322,49.31987") as url:

    Soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
lists = Soup.find_all('div', class_="container") 

with open('testing.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    for list in lists:
        Price = list.find('p', class_="listing-card_price").text
        Type = list.find('div', class_="listing-card__type-and-updated").text
        Title = list.find('div', class_="listing-card").text

        print(Price, Type, Title)
    ```
````

Comment: The content isn't static html, it's being populated by javascript. Take a look at the Network tab in Chrome->Developer Tools and it should be obvious. You need to use a tool which understands javascript, [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) is a popular python package which can do this.

Comment: another option is to look for an API you can use to get the data directly rather than scraping it from the web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is one way of obtaining that data - inspect browser's Dev tools - Network tab for any XHR calls, and then scrape that eventual API endpoint. Here is the code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://rentals.ca/phoenix/api/v1.0.2/listings?details=mid1&suppress-pagination=1&limit=350&bbox=-123.20298,49.13647,-122.75322,49.31987'

headers = {
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
s.get('https://rentals.ca/new-westminster?bbox=-123.20298,49.13647,-122.75322,49.31987')

r = s.get(url)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['data']['listings'])
print(df)
```

You get a quite comprehensive dataframe with the listings:

```
id  name    address1    address2    postal_code phone   url view_on_map_url city    format  title   featured_status photo_count raw_property_type   property_type   updated rent_range  beds_range  baths_range dimensions_range    location.lat    location.lng    location.x  location.y  photo.id    photo.url   photo.width photo.height    photo.priority  photo.unit_id   photo.scales.large.url  photo.scales.large.width    photo.scales.large.height   photo.scales.medium.url photo.scales.medium.width   photo.scales.medium.height  photo.scales.small.url  photo.scales.small.width    photo.scales.small.height
0   612435  None    1471 Hunter Street  405 V7J 1H3 None    https://rentals.ca/north-vancouver/1471-hunter-street-1 https://rentals.ca/north-vancouver/condos?active-listing-id=612435  6090785 proper  1471 Hunter Street  highlighted 1   condo   condo   2022-10-07T17:34:22.061Z    [3400.0, 3400.0]    [2.0, 2.0]  [2.0, 2.0]  [920.0, 920.0]  49.310450   -123.033497 -123.033497 49.310450   None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/north-vancouver-bc/612435/condo-13068950.jpg  4032    4032    11  None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/north-vancouver-bc/612435/condo-13068950.jpg  1440    1080    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/medium/north-vancouver-bc/612435/condo-13068950.jpg 1200    900 https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/small/north-vancouver-bc/612435/condo-13068950.jpg  480 360
1   632195  None    5475 199A Street    None    V3A 1J7 None    https://rentals.ca/langley/5475-199a-street https://rentals.ca/langley?active-listing-id=632195 6049430 proper  5475 199A Street    highlighted 1   town-house  town house  2022-10-05T18:55:29.314Z    [2950.0, 2950.0]    [3.0, 3.0]  [2.5, 2.5]  [1445.0, 1445.0]    49.101963   -122.670668 -122.670668 49.101963   None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/langley-bc/632195/town-house-13671405.jpg 5452    5452    11  None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/langley-bc/632195/town-house-13671405.jpg 1620    1080    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/medium/langley-bc/632195/town-house-13671405.jpg    1350    900 https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/small/langley-bc/632195/town-house-13671405.jpg 540 360
2   629540  Hub Place   1649 E Broadway None    None    (604) 714-4794  https://rentals.ca/vancouver/1649-e-broadway    https://rentals.ca/vancouver/apartments?active-listing-id=629540    6173331 proper  1649 E Broadway highlighted 1   apartment   apartment   2022-10-05T09:08:12.408Z    [1975.0, 4050.0]    [0.0, 3.0]  [1.0, 2.0]  [362.0, 1009.0] 49.262622   -123.071263 -123.071263 49.262622   None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/vancouver-bc/629540/apartment-13568421.jpg    1280    1280    11  None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/vancouver-bc/629540/apartment-13568421.jpg    1280    853 https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/medium/vancouver-bc/629540/apartment-13568421.jpg   1280    853 https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/small/vancouver-bc/629540/apartment-13568421.jpg    540 360
3   468498  Arbutus Residences  4188 Yew Street None    None    (604) 879-8407  https://rentals.ca/vancouver/4188-yew-street    https://rentals.ca/vancouver/apartments?active-listing-id=468498    6173331 proper  4188 Yew Street highlighted 1   apartment   apartment   2022-08-23T09:00:21.332Z    [2330.0, 10895.0]   [0.5, 4.0]  [1.0, 3.0]  [455.0, 2220.0] 49.248762   -123.154540 -123.154540 49.248762   None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/vancouver-bc/468498/apartment-5596387.jpg 1727    1727    11  None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/vancouver-bc/468498/apartment-5596387.jpg 1619    1080    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/medium/vancouver-bc/468498/apartment-5596387.jpg    1349    900 https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/small/vancouver-bc/468498/apartment-5596387.jpg 540 360
4   293930  9304 Salish Court   9304 Salish Court   None    None    (778) 960-6568  https://rentals.ca/burnaby/9304-salish-court    https://rentals.ca/burnaby/apartments?active-listing-id=293930  5911606 proper  9304 Salish Court   paid-feed   1   apartment   apartment   2022-10-10T09:11:13.322Z    [2402.0, 2402.0]    [1.0, 1.0]  [1.0, 1.0]  [784.0, 784.0]  49.251380   -122.901761 -122.901761 49.251380   None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/burnaby-bc/293930/apartment-2685394.jpg   1727    1727    11  None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/burnaby-bc/293930/apartment-2685394.jpg   1619    1080    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/medium/burnaby-bc/293930/apartment-2685394.jpg  1349    900 https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/small/burnaby-bc/293930/apartment-2685394.jpg   540 360
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
195 636694  None    6628 120 Street 1   V3W 1T7 (604) 356-9352  https://rentals.ca/surrey/6628-120-street   https://rentals.ca/surrey?active-listing-id=636694  6159905 proper  6628 120 Street None    1   private-room    private room    2022-10-06T11:14:04.174Z    [700.0, 700.0]  [3.0, 3.0]  [2.0, 2.0]  [1000.0, 1000.0]    49.123305   -122.889203 -122.889203 49.123305   None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/surrey-bc/636694/private-room-13739433.jpg    2448    2448    11  None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/surrey-bc/636694/private-room-13739433.jpg    810 1080    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/medium/surrey-bc/636694/private-room-13739433.jpg   675 900 https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/small/surrey-bc/636694/private-room-13739433.jpg    270 360
196 636691  None    138 East Hastings Street    None    V6A 1N6 (236) 237-3275  https://rentals.ca/vancouver/138-east-hastings-street   https://rentals.ca/vancouver/apartments?active-listing-id=636691    6173331 proper  138 East Hastings Street    None    1   apartment   apartment   2022-10-06T11:13:44.397Z    [2100.0, 2100.0]    [1.0, 1.0]  [1.0, 1.0]  [468.0, 468.0]  49.281213   -123.101304 -123.101304 49.281213   None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/vancouver-bc/636691/apartment-13739376.jpg    639 639 11  None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/vancouver-bc/636691/apartment-13739376.jpg    639 526 https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/medium/vancouver-bc/636691/apartment-13739376.jpg   639 526 https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/small/vancouver-bc/636691/apartment-13739376.jpg    437 360
197 636644  None    1526 Finlay Street  310 V4B 4L9 (604) 222-8425  https://rentals.ca/white-rock/1526-finlay-street-2  https://rentals.ca/white-rock/apartments?active-listing-id=636644   6180961 proper  1526 Finlay Street  None    1   apartment   apartment   2022-10-06T11:10:37.594Z    [3500.0, 3500.0]    [2.0, 2.0]  [2.0, 2.0]  [1070.0, 1070.0]    49.029799   -122.789784 -122.789784 49.029799   None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/white-rock-bc/636644/apartment-13737096.jpg   2016    2016    11  None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/white-rock-bc/636644/apartment-13737096.jpg   1440    1080    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/medium/white-rock-bc/636644/apartment-13737096.jpg  1200    900 https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/small/white-rock-bc/636644/apartment-13737096.jpg   480 360
198 636647  None    Highway 99  None    None    (604) 219-7378  https://rentals.ca/richmond/highway-99  https://rentals.ca/richmond/condos?active-listing-id=636647 6122085 proper  Highway 99  None    1   condo   condo   2022-10-06T11:07:45.240Z    [3100.0, 3100.0]    [2.0, 2.0]  [1.0, 1.0]  [720.0, 720.0]  49.170432   -123.086936 -123.086936 49.170432   None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/richmond-bc/636647/condo-13737142.jpg 4032    4032    11  None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/richmond-bc/636647/condo-13737142.jpg 1440    1080    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/medium/richmond-bc/636647/condo-13737142.jpg    1200    900 https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/small/richmond-bc/636647/condo-13737142.jpg 480 360
199 594287  14858 60 Avenue 14858 60 Avenue None    V3S 1R8 (604) 531-1111  https://rentals.ca/surrey/14858-60-avenue-8 https://rentals.ca/surrey/apartments?active-listing-id=594287   6159905 proper  14858 60 Avenue None    1   apartment   apartment   2022-10-06T09:25:21.357Z    [3530.0, 3530.0]    [3.0, 3.0]  [2.0, 2.0]  [1217.0, 1217.0]    49.111630   -122.810380 -122.810380 49.111630   None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/surrey-bc/594287/apartment-7406506.jpg    906 906 11  None    https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/large/surrey-bc/594287/apartment-7406506.jpg    906 605 https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/medium/surrey-bc/594287/apartment-7406506.jpg   906 605 https://images.rentals.ca/property-pictures/small/surrey-bc/594287/apartment-7406506.jpg    539 360
```

Documentation for Requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And for pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have tried the code above and it worked. After obtaining the data and exporting it to a CSV file. I have noticed that the price is not there.  Does it have to do with the info originally contained in the API that I scrape, or did I use the wrong API?

Comment: @NguyênVũTrầnMinh you can add `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)`, to see the full dataframe and export properly with `df.to_csv('rentals.csv')`. Prince should be under `rent range` column.